# One content type with multiple templates

Tags: content-type, document-template

I have a situation were I have to create multiple templates for one content type.
I am aware that this can be achieved by creating multiple content type but I am trying to have multiple templates attached to only one content type.

Is it possible. If yes how easy or hard it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done!

Take a look at how a Web Part Page is created - it directs you to an ASPX page in which you choose the layout. You could basically do the same thing for any content type.

Comment: Can you please direct me to a website some where I can read more about it. Thanks. Dig

Comment: This isn't exactly documented. But what really happens is that the content type template points to an .aspx file that does the trick for you. Check the default content types and files in the SharePoint root folders and mimic that.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is to my knowledge not possible.

Instead create a hierarchy of CT's where all your different templates are associated to a sibling CT

Answer (score 1):

Document Set is what you are looking for.

To elaborate, you can associate metatdata to a document set and have multiple templates associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to where this could be used, there is an OOB Document ContentType and it has by default (Site Content Types --> ContentTypeName --> Document Property Settings) 'Use the default template for Microsoft Office applications' set!

This will give you Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote, Excel Survey templates to choose from when you click 'New' in the dropdown.

Can we do somet similar for multitude of Doc templates, each for a specific purpose without the need to create a ContentType for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

No, We can't attach multiples templates to a Single content type. Because Each Content Type holds certain set of Properties and hold as a single template.
May I know, what kind of requirement needs for Multiple templates in a Single Content Type.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note to say that it would be great if someone could provide a little more info on how to implement the approach proposed by Wictor. I would have added this as a comment except I don't have enough rep points to do so. Cheers